# How to sign request with private key in Runscope test?

Tags: rsa, sha256, cryptojs, runscope

I am trying to add Runscope test to verify signature of the request I am sending. In first step I want to sign this request, and then send it to the service which is going to verify it.

I know I can add script in Runscope and that I can use CryptoJS for signing the request. However documentation for CryptoJS is not very helpful and I fail to sign my request;

I have something similar done in Postman using Crypto Postman lib, and the code is:

```
function encryptSignature(signingMetadata) {
            eval(pm.globals.get('pmlib_code'));
            var encryptedSignature = new pmlib.rs.KJUR.crypto.Signature({ "alg": "SHA256withRSA" });
            encryptedSignature.init(config.privateKey)
            var hash2 = encryptedSignature.signString(signingMetadata)
            const signedEncoded = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(hash2));
            return signedEncoded;
        }
```

trying to do something similar in Runscope I came up with this code:

```
function encryptSignature(signingMetadata) {
    var hash = CryptoJS.SHA256withRSA(signingMetadata, config.privateKey);
    var signedEncoded = hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
        return signedEncoded;
    }
```

but got error for undefined which I assume is CryptoJS;

I used some online JS compilers and when I import

```
import sha256 from 'crypto-js/sha256';
import Base64 from 'crypto-js/enc-base64';
```

and refactor code to:

```
var signedEncoded = Base64.stringify(sha256(signingMetadata, config.privateKey));
```

it compiles and does some kind of signing, but signature does not look right (it is way too short)

Anyone done this successfully before in Runscope? I would appreciate some advice;

Thank you,

Comment: CryptoJS doesn't support RSA or public key cryptography in general, but only symmetric encryption (like AES).

Comment: Is CryptoJS in Postman different then? As we successfully use it there. Just cannot make it work in Runscope. Probably need some kind of imports or sth, and a bit different implementation. Or maybe there is another lib I could use in Runscope?

Comment: In your code snippet you use [jsrsasign](https://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/api/symbols/KJUR.crypto.Signature.html) for signing with RSA. [CryptoJS](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#encoders) is only applied for the conversion from hex to Base64. Study the linked documentation. I don't know Runscope and can't say anything about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Topaco mentioned, CryptoJS doesn't support RSA cryptography.

You can generate signature using [jsrsasign](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsrsasign) and CryptoJS library however it's tricky to get this working due to Runscope limitations.
The following code snippet is generating signature:

```js
var signature = new KJUR.crypto.Signature({ "alg": "SHA256withRSA" });
signature.init(privateKey); // just key as a string
var hash = signature.signString("string to sign");
const encodedSignature = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(hash));
return encodedSignature;
```

but in order to get this working do the following:

1. from the `jsrsasign` repo, import `jsrsasign-rsa-min.js` and `keyutil-1.0.js` as a [Runscope script library / code snippet](https://blog.runscope.com/posts/using-snippets-and-script-libraries-monitor-aws-apis) (optionally merge these files together)
2. get rid of arrow functions (Runscope limitation).
3. get rid of all `window` references (Runscope limitation). jsrsasign uses this to detect older browsers - not necessary in this case as we run this script only in the Runscope environment.
4. (optionally) get rid of CryptoJS from the `jsrsasign-rsa-min.js` file as it's already available in the Runscope environment.
5. Import the above library to the test